# IPAddress.TryParse with input containing unicode

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, ip-address

Per MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.100).aspx, ipString can't contain Unicode characters or else ArgumentException will be thrown.

Is anyone able to repro in local console app, I tried multiple unicode characters but was not able to repro.

We saw similar error in some server logs:

> Cannot marshal: Encountered unmappable character. But was not able to log which input broke the code.

Update, part of the stack trace:
System.ArgumentExceptionMessage0: Cannot marshal: Encountered unmappable character. ;    at System.String.ConvertToAnsi(Int32 iMaxDBCSCharByteSize, Boolean fBestFit, Boolean fThrowOnUnmappableChar, Int32& cbLength)--   at System.StubHelpers.CSTRMarshaler.ConvertToNative(Int32 flags, String strManaged, IntPtr pNativeBuffer)--   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.WSAStringToAddress(String addressString, AddressFamily addressFamily, IntPtr lpProtocolInfo, Byte[] socketAddress, Int32& socketAddressSize)--   at System.Net.IPAddress.InternalParse(String ipString, Boolean tryParse)--   at System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(String ipString, IPAddress& address)--

Comment: Which characters did you try?

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN comment is somewhat strange (as any character even `1` is Unicode character)... and in general TryParse is not expected to throw when input is invalid text.

Your error seem to be related to marshaling (as in "calling COM object from managed code" or "PInvoke some native code"). If you are convinced that error coming from `TryParse` - the easiest approach could be to look at actual implementation of `TryParse` in System.Dll and try to trace back what input and in what environment can cause such exception.

Here is potential case (IPv6-like address with Russian characters):

```
  System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse("ф:ф", out v);
```

Comment: The case you gave doesn't repro... I've tried .net 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and in Win7/Win2k8R2.